# How does implicit conversions occur in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, language-lawyer

In SQLite, dynamic typing is used and implicit conversions are done in expressions. For example

```sql
SELECT (3 < 2); -- false
SELECT (3 < '2'); -- true (what's happning here?)
SELECT ('3' < '2'); -- false

SELECT (3 < 20); -- true
SELECT (3 < '20'); -- true (what's happning here?)
SELECT ('3' < '20'); -- false
```

But the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) and the O'REILLY book [*Using SQLite*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521196.do) say nothing about **how** operands are casted in implicit conversions.

In C++, [Standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) strictly defines (i.e. explicitly explains) how implicit conversions occur. For example, if either operand is of the type `long double`, another operand is casted to `long double`.

Is there such a rule in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3/4.1. Sort Order](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> An INTEGER or REAL value is **less than any TEXT** or BLOB value.

Obviously:

```
SELECT TYPEOF(3);
```

returns `integer`
and

```
SELECT TYPEOF('2');
SELECT TYPEOF('20');
```

return `text`.
So there is no conversion here:

```
SELECT 3 < '2';
```

which returns `true`.
**But** there is an implicit conversion in an expression like this:

```
SELECT 3 < '2' + 0;
```

which returns `false` and this conversion is forced by the operator `+` which applies a numeric operation to `'2'` thus converting it to an `integer`.
*Edit to clarify:*
This behavior applies only to literal values like `3` and `'2'`.
When it comes to expressions or column values then an implicit conversion **does happen.** 
So if you define a table like:

```
create table test(id integer); 
insert into test(id) values (1), (2), (3);
```

a statement like:

```
select * from test where id > '1'
```

will return:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
| 3   |
```

see the [demo](http://db-fiddle.com/f/anoFt2dDorYUgzZmow3uQc/1).

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot. But I just noticed a strange behavior. `SELECT (1 >= '1'), (CAST ('1' AS INTEGER) >= '1');` returns `0` and `1` whereas it is expected to return `0` and `0` according to the rule. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's more complicated than that. The rule that I mention in my answer applies to literal values like 1, '1'. When it comes to expressions or column values then an implicit conversion does happen. So if you define a table like: `create table test(id integer);` and then insert like this: `insert into test(id) values (1), (2), (3);` a statement like: `select * from test where id > '1'` will return `2, 3` (check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anoFt2dDorYUgzZmow3uQc/1) which means that an implicit conversion does happen. So there is no conversion on literal values only.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversions sometimes occur but sometimes don't. The conditions which determine whether conversions are done before comparisons are described in [*4.2. Type Conversions Prior To Comparison*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison). According to the section,

> Affinity is applied to operands of a comparison operator prior to the comparison according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> - If one operand has INTEGER, REAL or NUMERIC affinity and the other operand has TEXT or BLOB or no affinity then NUMERIC affinity is applied to other operand.
> - If one operand has TEXT affinity and the other has no affinity, then TEXT affinity is applied to the other operand.
> - Otherwise, no affinity is applied and both operands are compared as is.

But how is the type affinity of an expression (including literals) defined? It is explained in [*3.2. Affinity Of Expressions*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_of_expressions) as

> Every table column has a type affinity (one of BLOB, TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, or NUMERIC) but expressions do no necessarily have an affinity.
>
> Expression affinity is determined by the following rules:
>
> - The right-hand operand of an IN or NOT IN operator has no affinity if the operand is a list and has the same affinity as the affinity of the result set expression if the operand is a SELECT.
> - When an expression is a simple reference to a column of a real table (not a VIEW or subquery) then the expression has the same affinity as the table column.
>
>   1. Parentheses around the column name are ignored. Hence if X and Y.Z are column names, then (X) and (Y.Z) are also considered column names and have the affinity of the corresponding columns.
>   2. Any operators applied to column names, including the no-op unary "+" operator, convert the column name into an expression which always has no affinity. Hence even if X and Y.Z are column names, the expressions +X and +Y.Z are not column names and have no affinity.
> - An expression of the form "CAST(expr AS type)" has an affinity that is the same as a column with a declared type of "type".
> - A COLLATE operator has the same affinity as its left-hand side operand.
> - Otherwise, an expression has no affinity.

So in the cases of examples in OP, literals have no affinity and are thus compared as-is. Since

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

as pointed out in [forpas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60828883/8776746), `3 < '2'` returns `true`.

These rules correctly describes apparently strange behavior referred to in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828571/how-does-implicit-conversions-occur-in-sqlite#comment107622919_60828883). `CAST ('1' AS INTEGER)` **does** have the type affinity `INTEGER` so that `>= '1'` is interpreted as `>= 1` and thus `CAST ('1' AS INTEGER) >= '1'` returns `true` whereas `1 >= '1'` returns `false`.